# How does extern "C" work in C++?

Tags: c++, extern-c

I see some code in C++ using `extern "C"` at the beginning of the file like this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus 
extern "C" {} 
#endif
```

What does this mean? How does it work?

Comment: Good information on extern "c" here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/what-does-extern-c-in-c-source

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably not like that, but more like:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus 
extern "C" {
#endif

//some includes or declarations

#ifdef __cplusplus 
}
#endif
```

It tells the compiler to use `C` name mangling for whatever is declared inside the directives.

The way you have it now:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus 
extern "C" {} 
#endif
```

is just dead code.

Comment: but the code I saw is:#ifdef __cplusplus  extern "C" {}  #endif , so is it wrong code?

Comment: @ratzip it's not wrong, it's just dead code. It does nothing.

Comment: It tells the compiler (not the linker) to use C conventions for the functions, rather than C++.  This involves not only name mangling, but the conventions for passing arguments, and possibly other things as well.

Comment: @JamesKanze are you saying the linker doesn't need to know about name mangling?

Comment: Not at all. The compiler mangles names. The linker joins up whatever names it's given to whatever names its's asked-for.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Not necessarily.  About the only time most linkers take name mangling into account is when outputting error messages.

Answer (score 5):

It is used to inform the compiler to disable C++ name mangling for the functions defined within the braces. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling

Comment: +1 you said in one line what I was going to say in 100. Well done.

Answer (score 0):

It specifies a **[linkage specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6y4zxec%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)**.
It tells the linker how to link the code.

It is useful when you want to **[mix C and C++ code](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html)**.

Comment: @Nawaz: And who said so? The `"C"`is.

Answer (score 0):

`Extern "C"` -  notify the compiler,that the noted function is compiled in C style.