# how to compile cpp and c together using clang++

Tags: c++, c, compilation, symbols, clang++

I have some code in cpp (where the main() lies) and want to call functions located in a c file. Compiling the cpp's and the c's give the output .o files, but when using clang++ to generate the final executable, it is failing because the cpp is unable to find the c function:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "FunctionInCFile(char const*, char const*, int, int, int, int)", referenced from:
      FunctionInCPPFile() in helixQtCmd.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Comment: Use `extern C { }` to wrap the c language function declarations.

Comment: Or simply compile all your sources with clang++.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how does "extern c" works in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190455/how-does-extern-c-works-in-c)

Comment: Mmmh, getting 'error: expected unqualified-id extern "C" {' when compiling. Any clue why ?

Comment: It's EASIER to just compile all files with the C++ compiler, if it works. Otherwise, you will need to put `#if __cplusplus` around the `extern "C" {` (and the `}` that goes with it.

Comment: Compiling with clang++ doesn't really work as option as it finds plenty errors in the c code that clang accepts.